# Silhouette from an image

Tags: scripting, images, imagemagick, image-manipulation

How can I create silhouette from an image in linux using the terminal?

By creating silhouette I mean - how do I turn the RGB components values of an RGBA image to #000000, while *preserving* the alpha component value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `convert` from `ImageMagick`:

```
convert <input_image> -fill '#000' +opaque '#000' <output_image>
```

What it does it changes all the colors not matching `#000` to `#000`.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer didn't work for me (it filled the entire image, including the transparent area) but this did:

```
convert input.png -fill "cyan" -colorize 100 output.png
```